# I get an error when calling writeString on EDX?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I've been doing an assignment in Visual Studio that is supposed to print out an array of characters in a "box" fashion, where after every 4 characters there is a newline.

But when I try to call the Irvine32 writeString function the second time, the program produces an Access violation reading location error.

Here is my code (I'm using DWORD, that's why I'm incrementing by 4):

```
mov esi, OFFSET array1 
mov ebx, totalSize
mov eax, counter

forLoop: 

cmp eax, ebx 
jae loopExit
mov edx, 0 
mov edx, [esi + eax * 4]
call writeString
jmp forLoop
```

I even tried to make it more simple by using addition instead and it still didn't work:

```
mov esi, OFFSET array1 
mov ebx, totalSize
mov eax, counter

forLoop: 

cmp eax, ebx 
jae loopExit
mov edx, 0 
mov edx, esi 
call writeString
mov ecx, 4
mov esi, [esi + 4]
jmp forLoop
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong here. I just believe it to be something wrong with the pointer or writeString, but I don't know what.

Thanks for any help, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Both versions check `eax` without incrementing which should at least be an infinite loop. The second version has `mov esi, [esi + 4]` which is wrong. Unfortunately you did not provide a [mcve] but based on your description you have a single array of characters which you want to print 4 at a time. That's not how you do it, as the `WriteString` expects a pointer and it does not take a count. You should use `WriteChar` 4 times.

Comment: @Jester the eax not incrementing is something I noticed and just didn't fix in the example, my bad. However, I know that writeString takes a pointer. My goal was to iterate through the array using the esi pointer, and then to change the value being passed to EDX to the next value in the array, which would be the new ESI value. That's why I was giving EDX the ESI value, because EDX is the pointer for writeString to print. I'm not trying to get writeString to print 4 characters at once, I'm trying to get it to loop through the array (which includes the newline/linebreak).

Comment: Here is an image containing the full program:

https://i.imgur.com/4Ghkgb2.png

and the addition version:

https://i.imgur.com/IDYWN3H.png

Comment: 1) Your strings are not 4 bytes apart. 2) Don't use `dword` for string data; use `db`. 3) Don't use `mov` for pointer arithmetic; use `lea` (or `add` if that's a possibility).

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the help, but isn't dword data in an array always 4 bytes apart?

Comment: Note if you have the newlines already embedded you can write the whole thing at once without a loop.

Comment: _"but isn't dword data in an array always 4 bytes apart?"_ `"ABCD",0Dh,0Ah` is 6 characters, so that's _at least_ 6 bytes. Actually with your current code where you're incorrectly using `dword` you'e actually getting the byte sequence `'D','C','B','A',0Dh,0,0,0,0Ah,0,0,0`, so that's 12 bytes (also note the order of the characters). If you switched to `db` you get the correct byte sequence `'A','B','C','D',0Dh,0Ah`, but that's still 6 bytes, not 4 (and you're missing the string NUL terminator).